# Specific OU for each domain

Tags: powershell

I am creating a script to fetch workstations from each domain from a specific OU in each domain. The "specific OU" is unique for each domain.

```
function Get-Workstations {
    param (
      [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true)]
      [ValidateSet("domain1", "domain2", "domain3", "domain4", "domain5", 
      "domain5")]
    [String[]]$Domain
    )

$domain1OU = "OU=Computers,OU=Corporate,DC=domain1,DC=com,DC=au"
$domain2OU = "OU=Workstations,OU=Corporate2,DC=domain2,DC=com,DC=au"
$domain3OU = "OU=AccountsWS,OU=MyCorporate,DC=domain3,DC=com,DC=au"
$domain4OU = "OU=Dev,OU=WS,OU=Company,DC=domain4,DC=com,DC=au"
$domain5OU = "OU=Computers,OU=WebDevs,DC=domain5,DC=com,DC=au"

Begin {
    $DomainLookup = @{
        domain1 = "domain1.com.au"
        domain2 = "domain2.com.au"
        domain3 = "domain3.com.au"
        domain4 = "domain4.com.au"
        domain5 = "domain5.com.au"
    }

}
Process {
    ForEach ( $DName in $Domain ) {
        If ( $DomainLookup.Contains($Domain) ) {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Domain Name $DName found"

            if ( $DName -eq $DomainLookup.Values('domain1') ) {
                $workstations = Get-ADComputer -Server adc1.$domain1 -SearchBase $domain1OU -Filter * | Sort-Object -Property Name | Select-Object Name
            }

        }
    }

    #$workstations = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $domain1OU -Filter * | Sort-Object -Property Name | Select-Object Name

}
End {
    return $workstations
}
```

}

The above function is part of a greater powershell module that I am trying to create for our company. The user should call the function from the shell and give one or more domains with the -Domain parameter and get a list of those workstations.

Comment: what is the question? [*grin*]

Comment: Sorry my bad. The above script does not function as I thought. When I give a domain it does not fetch the workstations under that domains OU. That's why I have comment the the ` #$workstations = Get... ` part. I can make it work outside from the loop or the if. Did that make any sense ?

Comment: yes, but you need to add that to your Original Post so others can find it. [*grin*] try to include what you ACTUALLY get, & what you WANT to get from it so folks can get a good idea of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please make the following alterations to your code:

```
Process {
    ForEach ( $DName in $Domain ) {
        If ( $DomainLookup.Contains($DName) ) {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Domain Name $DName found"

            if ( $DomainLookup['domain1'].Contains($DName) ) {
                $workstations = Get-ADComputer -Server ("{0}.{1}" -f "adc1",$domainlookup['domain1']) -SearchBase $domain1OU -Filter * |
                                Sort-Object -Property Name | Select-Object Name
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since `$Domain` could contain an array of values, you will need to check for each object value in that array within the hashtable object's `.Contains()` method. In your case, that value is represented by `$DName`.

In the first `If` statement, the `.Contains()` method checks for the key value rather than the value in the key-value pair. See [About_Hash_Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-6) for referencing hash table keys and values. See [Hashtable .Contains(Object) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.contains?view=netframework-4.8) for how the `Hashtable.Contains` method works.

When referencing the value of a particular key, you can do that in at least two ways. One way is using a key name as a named index like `$DomainLookup['Domain1']`. A second way is to use the key name as a property name like `$DomainLookup.Domain1`. In either case, a variable can be used as the index name or property name. For example, `$DomainLookup.$DName` can be used.

Keep in mind that in the second `if` statement, the `.Contains()` method is from the `String` class. The method there is doing a substring comparison of the string value returned by accessing a particular key's value. See [String.Contains Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netframework-4.8) for how the `.Contains(Value)` method works from the String class.

The `Get-ADComputer` command needed a change, specifically the value passed to the `-Server` parameter. Since you want to append a value from the hash table to the string `adc1`, you need to properly retrieve that value. Your original statement could work but you would need to assign `$domain1` with a value from your hash table.

As a side note, you probably don't need nested if statements. I left them there in case there is more that your code is doing beyond what is posted.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!!! I got so stuck in this and I could not figure out what I was missing. Yes I did have in my mind to the ` -Server ` parameter but later. The portion of this script was just the first step to test the water of how things will work. Still the whole project is in its early stage. Eventually I will post it in an online version control website.